# why does an Elasticsearch query return no records?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a small Elasticsearch cluster. One record looks like this:

```
        "hits" : [
          {
            "_index" : "readiness",
            "_type" : "council_doc",
            "_id" : "4sqzhGwBkqm_VQwAkam8",
            "_score" : 6.4425545,
            "_source" : {
              "code" : "E06000001",
              "council_name" : "Hartlepool",
              "council_response" : "Refused",
              "response_type" : "3"
            }
          }
        ]
```

This is produced by the following Curl query:

```
{
  "query": { "match": { "council_name": "Hartlepool" } }
}
```

As you can see one of the fields is called "code" and when I attempt to run a query, to get the same result, but searching by the code field as follows it produces no results:

```
 {
      "query": { "match": { "code": "E06000001" } }
    }
```

I don't get an error message, I just get zero hits. I am mystified, can anybody help? Both the code field and the council_name filed have the same mapping properties: keyword.

The mapping is:

```
{
  "readiness" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "council_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "council_response" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "response_type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "code" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/readiness/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>   "query": { "match": { "code.keyword": "E06000001" } }
> }
> '
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your index mapping, please?

Comment: thanks, I have updated question to show mapping. While we are on the subject, I tried to add "fielddata":true to the council_response field but I could not do that either!

Answer (score 0):

According to your mapping, your query should work (I could reproduce and it worked). You may also want to try the following query (i.e. on the `.keyword` sub-field):

```
{
  "query": { "match": { "code.keyword": "E06000001" } }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I still cannot get it to work. I have updated the question with example. Please take a look.

Comment: Is the mapping you showed the mapping you think you have installed or the one that you got from ES? i.e. what do you get when running `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/readiness`?

Comment: they are identical. I tried both ready and readiness to see if having a different index made any difference.

Comment: It's not critical to my project, I am just mystified as I said that it does not work for me.

Comment: Puzzling... Can you provide a gist to reproduce your exact environment and index?

Comment: thanks, got it. I will do it tomorrow. We should finish this for the benefit of others who have the same problem. And thank you for your help.